# what's user of static object filed in service layer

Tags: java, class, static, field

in my class AccountService ther is Static filed AccountDao which is also class why we need to declare as static i know this will we use for accessing
classname.staticfield access every where in class but what use for with other class object declare as static??  thanks in advance

```
 public class AccountService {

private static AccountDao accountinfo;

public AccountService() {
    accountinfo = new AccountDao();
} }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Can you try to explain what your problem is here in more detail? And please use punctuation.

Comment: Sorry don't understand your question. Can you try and be more clear?

Comment: I doubt I get your question fully. You can get a static field in a class without creating an instance of a class irrespective of it's of primitive type or  a class type.

Comment: what is the use of  static for declaring other class object as static ??

Answer (score 2):

Static members are shared by all instances of a class. In your example, all instances of `AccountService` may access just one instance of `AccountDao` called `accountinfo`.

Why this is done in your case, I do not know. To make it worse, every time a new instance of `AccountService` is created `accountinfo` is instantiated again. That means that an older instance cannot refer to the original object of `accountinfo` once another instance of `AccountService` is created.

Generally, there are a number of reasons why static members are used, e.g. logical (1:n relationship), performance (all objects share one ressource). Whatever the reason is: be careful when and how to (re-)instantiate a static member as all objects of that class may want to use this member at different times.